# Parsing XML tags nested within other XML values

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, jaxp

I am stuck developing a specific XML parser which parses huge chunk of XML .

My problem is i'm confused how to parse XML tags nested within other XML values.
My input file looks something like this.

```
<main>
<step>
    <para>Calculate the values from the pool</para>
</step>
<step>
        <para>Use these(<internalRef id ="003" xlink:actuate="onRequest" xlink:show="replace" xlink:href="max003"/>) values finally</para>
</step>
</main>
```

I am able to get the values of the first step tag using xpath.
My problem is how to get the second step values using xpath or rather how to identify when a new tag is starting within a value tag.

For Eg, My second step xpath is returning me this result - **Use these () values finally**

where as my aim is to get-  **Use these (*max003*) values finally**

The **max003** values has to be taken from ***xlink:href***

***Addition*** - I am able to get individual values of id , actuate, show by writing separate xpaths. My question is i need to stuff the **max003** value inside the parentheses after **these** and before **values**  after getting the **xlink:href** value which is ***max003*** and send it across the wire for display.  ***So i am searching for a way to identify where and when the sub node id has started?*** and **a mechanism to stuff it inside the parentheses .**

Comment: Or is this a case of invalid XML?

Comment: I think you might find that the parse is seeing the internal tags as sub nodes to the `<para>` node...ie `<para>`->`<id>`

Comment: there is no such thing as nested xml tags in xml values.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Can you elaborate it please ?

Comment: @AndreasHenning : Couldn't frame a better question than this ! Appreciate your help in refining it

Comment: Refined the question, see the addition part. Thanks

Comment: It's hard to answer your question without knowing (a) what other possible inputs it has to deal with, and (b) what you want to do with the data: what's the output of your program? In addition, your sample isn't well-formed - there's no attribute name before the `="003"`

Comment: @MichaelKay : Sorry for the mistakes in the attribute field though, i had to write a sample file illustrating my problem with the original XML file.
(a) There are several other similar references in the same input file.
(b)  I want to send the step by step instructions to display in the front, so even before sending it to the client side, i wanted to resolve the id references within the parentheses and just send a plain string across the wire. i.e , " Use these (max003) values finally ". Thanks !

Comment: Is using XSLT to transform the entire document by replacing occurrences the way you specified and then using xpath on the trasformed document an option? It would be trivial to make such a transformation with XSLT. You said that the document is huge so this might be too much overhead. Have you considered using an XML pull parser, eg. a java StAX implementation, to extract the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The evaluation of this Xpath expression:**

```
 concat(/*/step[2]/para/text()[1],
        /*/step[2]/para/internalRef/@xlink:href,
        /*/step[2]/para/text()[2])
```

on the provided XML document (corrected to be namespace-wellformed):

```
<main xmlns:xlink="Undefined namespace">
    <step>
        <para>Calculate the values from the pool</para>
    </step>
    <step>
        <para>Use these(<internalRef id ="003" xlink:actuate="onRequest" xlink:show="replace" xlink:href="max003"/>) values finally</para>
    </step>
</main>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
Use these(max003) values finally
```

**Do note**: You will need to "register the xlink namespace" with your XPath API, in order for this XPath expression to be evaluated without an error.

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xlink="Undefined namespace">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "concat(/*/step[2]/para/text()[1],
           /*/step[2]/para/internalRef/@xlink:href,
           /*/step[2]/para/text()[2])
     "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document (above), the Xpath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
Use these(max003) values finally
```

Comment: What if his <para> element may contain multiple <internalRef> elements and text between each of them? Can this be solved with an XPath expression in a generic way?

Comment: @predi, Yes, with XPath 2.0. Yes, with XPath 1.0 if the number and exact type of all children of `para` is known in advance. No, with XPath 1.0 if the number and exact type of all children of `para` isn't known in advance

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to do that using XPath alone. What you have there is mixed content XML, meaning that an element may contain both a text value and sub-elements. You can only reference one of those at a time using XPath, and you also cannot just concat what you get from multiple XPath expressions, since the text value may surround the sub-elements as you state in your example.

I suggest you either use XSLT to transform the document and then query the transformed document using XPath as you do now. An alternative is to write your own parser which is able to handle your nested element properly.

This XSLT will probably work for you (haven't tested thoroughly):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="internalRef">
        <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course you then need to use an XSLT Processor in order to transform your original document.

And a parser could look like this (note that this is just skeleton code for a StAX parser):

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Attribute;
import javax.xml.stream.events.Characters;
import javax.xml.stream.events.EndElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.StartElement;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

public class ExampleStAXParser {

    private static final int STATE_UNDEFINED = 1;
    private static final int STATE_MAIN = 2;
    private static final int STATE_STEP = 3;
    private static final int STATE_PARA = 4;

    private static final String EL_MAIN = "main";
    private static final String EL_STEP = "step";
    private static final String EL_PARA = "para";
    private static final String EL_INTERNAL_REF = "internalRef";
    private static final String ATT_HREF = "href";

    private int state = STATE_UNDEFINED;
    private String characters;

    public void parse(String xmlString) throws XMLStreamException, Exception {


        XMLEventReader reader = null;
        try {
            if (xmlString == null || xmlString.isEmpty()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal initializiation (xmlString is null or empty)");
            }
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString);
            XMLInputFactory inputFact = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFact.createXMLStreamReader(stringReader);
            reader = inputFact.createXMLEventReader(streamReader);

            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();

                if (event.isCharacters()) {
                    characters(event);
                }
                if (event.isStartElement()) {
                    startElement(event);
                    // handle attributes
                    Iterator<Attribute> attributes = event.asStartElement().getAttributes();
                    while(attributes.hasNext()) {
                        attribute(attributes.next());
                    }
                }
                if (event.isEndElement()) {
                    endElement(event);
                }
                if (event.isStartDocument()) {
                    startDocument(event);
                }
                if (event.isEndDocument()) {
                    endDocument(event);
                }

            }            
        } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (XMLStreamException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    private void attribute(XMLEvent event) throws Exception {
        if (state == STATE_PARA) {
            Attribute attr = (Attribute) event;
            String name = attr.getName().getLocalPart();
            if (ATT_HREF.equals(name)) {
                if (characters == null) {
                    characters = attr.getValue();
                } else {
                     characters += attr.getValue();
                }
            }
        } else
            throw new Exception("unexpected attribute");
    }

    private void characters(XMLEvent event) throws Exception {
        Characters asCharacters = event.asCharacters();
        if (asCharacters.isWhiteSpace())
            return;
        if (state == STATE_PARA) {            
            if (characters == null) {
                characters = asCharacters.getData();
            } else {
                 characters += asCharacters.getData();
            }
        } else
            throw new Exception("unexpected attribute");
    }

    private void startElement(XMLEvent event) throws Exception {
        StartElement startElement = event.asStartElement();
        String name = startElement.getName().getLocalPart();
        switch (state) {
            case STATE_UNDEFINED:
                if (name.equals(EL_MAIN)) {
                    state = STATE_MAIN;
                    System.out.println("Element: " + name);
                } else
                    throw new Exception("unexpected element");
                break;
            case STATE_MAIN:
                if (name.equals(EL_STEP)) {
                    state = STATE_STEP;
                    System.out.println("Element: " + name);
                } else
                    throw new Exception("unexpected element");
                break;
            case STATE_STEP:
                if (name.equals(EL_PARA)) {
                    state = STATE_PARA;
                    System.out.println("Element: " + name);
                } else
                    throw new Exception("unexpected element");
                break;
            case STATE_PARA:
                if (name.equals(EL_INTERNAL_REF)) {
                    System.out.println("Element: " + name);
                } else
                    throw new Exception("unexpected element");
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("unexpected element");
        }
    }

    private void endElement(XMLEvent event) throws Exception {
        EndElement endElement = event.asEndElement();
        String name = endElement.getName().getLocalPart();
        switch (state) {
            case STATE_MAIN:
                if (name.equals(EL_MAIN)) {
                    state = STATE_UNDEFINED;
                } else
                    throw new Exception("unexpected element");
                break;
            case STATE_STEP:
                if (name.equals(EL_STEP)) {
                    state = STATE_MAIN;
                } else
                    throw new Exception("unexpected element");
                break;
            case STATE_PARA:
                if (name.equals(EL_INTERNAL_REF)) {
                    // do nothing
                } else if (name.equals(EL_PARA)) {
                    System.out.println("Value: " + String.valueOf(characters));
                    characters = null;
                    state = STATE_STEP;
                } else
                    throw new Exception("unexpected element");
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("unexpected element");
        }
    }

    private void startDocument(XMLEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Parsing started");
    }

    private void endDocument(XMLEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Parsing ended");
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws XMLStreamException, Exception {
        String xml = "";
        xml += "<main>";
        xml += "<step>";
        xml += "    <para>Calculate the values from the pool</para>";
        xml += "</step>";
        xml += "<step>";
        xml += "        <para>Use these(<internalRef id =\"003\" actuate=\"onRequest\" show=\"replace\" href=\"max003\"/>) values finally</para>";
        xml += "</step>";
        xml += "</main>";

        ExampleStAXParser parser = new ExampleStAXParser();
        parser.parse(xml);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As near as I can tell I think your parser is look at you structure a little like

```
step
 +- para
     +-id
```

It's then wrapping the "text" content together be extract that id node...

(This pure speculation)

**UPDATE**

If I simply walk the node tree (listing each child) this is what I get

```
 main
  step
    para
      #text - Calculate the values from the pool
  step
    para
      #text - Use these(
      id
      #text - ) values finally
```

This means that "id" is a child of "para"